# Average case complexity of Linear search

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, linear-search

All tutorials and wikipedia says that the complexity of linear search for average case is **n/2**. I know that the precise answer is **(n+1)/2** which is derived from the formula **(1+2+...+n)/n**.

My question is, why the sources say n/2 and not (n+1)/2? Aren't they wrong?

Comment: Your question doesn't provide enough information to be able to answer. Are you assuming that the item being searched for is always in the list, and that the first occurrence of it is equally likely to be in any location in the input array? And you are asking about complexity, but you're expecting an exact result like n/2 or (n+1)/2. Is the question about the average number of comparisons performed, or are you only interested in the complexity class?

Comment: Wikipedia says " If each element is equally likely to be searched, then linear search has an average case of (n+1)/2 comparisons, but the average case can be affected if the search probabilities for each element vary." although in the side-box it says the average performance is O(n/2). Since (n+1)/2 = O(n/2) = O(n) I don't think wikipedia is wrong in the way that you say.

Comment: @PaulHankin I want to know why some sources say that the complexity is n/2 and others say (n+1)/2. What's the basis for both answers?

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Thanks @PaulHankin

Comment: n/2 and (n+1)/2 are much more than just big-oh of each other. They are [asymptotically equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis)

Comment: I got your point @Stef. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Answered by @PaulHankin

Wikipedia says " If each element is equally likely to be searched, then linear search has an average case of (n+1)/2 comparisons, but the average case can be affected if the search probabilities for each element vary." although in the side-box it says the average performance is O(n/2). Since (n+1)/2 = O(n/2) = O(n)

Answered by @Stef

n/2 and (n+1)/2 are much more than just big-oh of each other. They are [asymptotically equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).